# Spark/Cassandra shaded dependency issue

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I'm trying to stream SSTables from spark to cassandra. I'm building a fat jar with SBT, which includes the following assembly shade rule:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "shaded.google.common.@1").inAll
)
```

This is done because spark has a different version of guava than what some Cassandra libraries require.

However, upon trying to stream SSTables in the executor, I see the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shaded.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Lshaded/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lshaded/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback;)V
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.addEventListener(StreamResultFuture.java:143)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamManager.register(StreamManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.createAndRegister(StreamResultFuture.java:130)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.init(StreamResultFuture.java:83)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamPlan.execute(StreamPlan.java:190)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:169)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:154)
    ...
```

This is confusing to me because it can't find the shaded class apparently. Yet I'm including the jar with the shaded class using the `--jars` option.

Any idea what to try here?

Comment: can you post your build.sbt ?

Comment: what version of spark connector? also please clarify why you need spark to stream SSTables?

Comment: @AlexOtt I'm streaming SSTables as opposed to writing in order to get better throughput. It apparently puts less load on the cluster.

Comment: I posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838345/bulk-loading-into-cassandra-streaming-vs-writing

Comment: from my point of view, use of Spark is easier - if it overloads the cluster, then you can just tune it to put less load.  You can also try to look to DSBulk - quite versatile & flexible tool for data loading from CSV/JSON files

Comment: @AlexOtt thank, I'll take a look at DSBulk

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my project includes several different versions of guava in the transitive dependencies. SBT picked the most recent version, which is not compatible with Cassandra.

My solution was to build a separate fat jar with just Cassandra + shaded guava, and include that jar at runtime.

Comment: you can also look onto the new Spark Connector (2.5) - it uses another Java driver, and should have less problems with Guava